# how to insert upper case in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i would like to know how to insert a upper case in mysql. i have a form that ask the user for their name, when they enter their for example tom brown. I would like to insert this into the db as Tom Brown instead. where would i need to put ucfirst for this to happen. i tried

```
$info = mysql_query("INSERT INTO workname(email,fname,lname,gender,position) VALUES
                   ('$email',ucfirst'$fname',ucfirst'$lname','$gender','$position' )"); 
      // didn't work

$info = mysql_query("INSERT INTO workname(email,fname,lname,gender,position) VALUES
            ucfirst('$email','$fname','$lname','$gender','$position' )");
  // not what i want, didn't work

$info = mysql_query("INSERT INTO workname(email,fname,lname,gender,position) VALUES
              ('$email',ucfirst('$fname'),ucfirst('$lname'),'$gender','$position' )");
 //  didn't work
```

Please help where and what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this php? try this.

```
$info = mysql_query("INSERT INTO workname(email,fname,lname,gender,position) VALUES
     ('$email','".ucfirst($fname)."','".ucfirst($lname)."','$gender','$position' )");
```

or this much better

```
$fname = ucfirst($fname);
$lname= ucfirst($lname);

$info = mysql_query("INSERT INTO workname (email,fname,lname,gender,position) VALUES
                          ('$email','$fname','$lname','$gender','$position' )");
```

Comment: @user621799 that's your MAIN problem. while trying to stuff everything in just one line of code, you'll always be in trouble. deep trouble

Comment: dont forget to sanitize your values :p